# ¿Cómo actualizo un JTextField de manera automática al editar una celda de un JTable en Java?

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un JTable y un JTextField [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que al editar la columna de cant el textfield se actualice con la cantidad que hay de stock que seria la cantidad por el precio de venta que es P.D.V, yo lo hice hasta cierto punto usando el evento click del jtable pero lo actualiza solamente si le das click y quiero que sea automático, aquí esta el código, no se que evento me puedan recomendar o cual seria mejor

```
public class Cotizar extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  DefaultTableModel modelo_tabla = (DefaultTableModel) tablaCliente.getModel();
```

}

```
private void tablaClienteMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        int columna, fila = 0;
        int CantidadBD = 0;
        DefaultTableModel ModeloClientes = (DefaultTableModel) tablaCliente.getModel();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        fila = tablaCliente.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        columna = tablaCliente.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (columna == 1) {
            Object id = ModeloClientes.getValueAt(fila, columna);
            String ide = id.toString();
            int numero = Integer.parseInt(ide);
            String sql2 = "Select cant_exist from Repuesto where Estado=? and nombre=? order by Nombre";
            ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ps.setBoolean(1, true);
            ps.setString(2, (String) ModeloClientes.getValueAt(fila, 3));
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                CantidadBD = (int) rs.getInt(1);
            }
            Object NuevaCantidad = ModeloClientes.getValueAt(fila, columna);
            String NuevaCantidad2 = NuevaCantidad.toString();
            int CantidadEditada = Integer.parseInt(NuevaCantidad2);               
            if (CantidadBD != CantidadEditada) {
                Object PrecioVenta = ModeloClientes.getValueAt(fila, 7);
                String PrecioVentaString = PrecioVenta.toString();
                int PrecioVentaInt = Integer.parseInt(PrecioVentaString);
                CantidadBD = (PrecioVentaInt * CantidadBD);
                total = total - CantidadBD;
                total += CantidadEditada * PrecioVentaInt;
                TextFieldTotal.setText(total);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cotizar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un @Override de `editingStopped(ChangeEvent)`:

```
public class Cotizar extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JTable tablaCliente = new MiTabla();
    DefaultTableModel modelo_tabla = (DefaultTableModel) tablaCliente.getModel();
    // vi que usas TextFieldTotal, te recomiendo dejar nombres de variables en minusculas
    // así queda más claro en el código que es clase y que es variable.
    JTextField textFieldTotal = new JTextField();

    // viene tu constructor, donde armas todas las componentes etc...

    public class MiTabla extends JTable{
        @Override
        public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e){
            int column = getEditingColumn();
            int row = getEditingRow();
            super.editingStopped(e);
            if (column!=1) return; // no estamos editando Cant, así fuera de aquí
            int nuevaCantidad = Integer.parseInt(getValueAt(row, column));
            // ...tu código para calcular el String total como quieras

            // en una "inner class", podemos acceder los campos de la clase externa
            textFieldTotal.setText(total);
        }
    }
```

Comment: este método iría dentro del evento del cliked?

Comment: la verdad no, si me pudieras ayudar en eso te lo agradecería

Comment: lo edite con la clase y donde instancio el jtable

Comment: no lo instancie

Comment: pero dame un ejemplo no importa algo con lo que me pueda guiar